# Someway to export a hand (or tablet) sketch to tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pstricks, inkscape

I wanted to know if there is some webpage or app that can transform a drawing made in a tablet to a tikz code or a pdf of the same quality for papers.

I come up with an idea and sketch it in my tablet and thought of how fun and nice it would be to do my images in here instead of using Inkscape or tikz code.

Or if you know of a good app to do serious sketches using the tablet it would also be wonderful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Could be interesting to know for what purpose you want to export those sketches of yours. And what kind of sketches it is.

Comment: why tikz, you can draw then include the resulting image. (choice of drawing app isn't really on topic here though)

Comment: but I draw by hand, is not a presentable quality vector image

Comment: use program `potrace` and you'll get a vector image of your hand drawing

Comment: I will try this!

Comment: @user202729 while the question is exactly the same, I think neither of the two answers actually answers the question. So to get a better chance of getting this answered maybe it's better to leave this one open and close the other one as a duplicate of this one if it is properly answered.

Comment: @Marijn How is that better? If we close this one as duplicate of the other, then anyone wanting to post an answer to this question can also repost it to the other; but if we close the other one as a duplicate of this, then answers in the other question loses visibility.

Comment: @user202729 it could be better because if this question is closed people might just skip it instead of going to the other question and write an answer there, while they would post the answer if this question is still open (because this question is new and visible). However, it is only better if that actually happens. Note however that the third question about this that came up in the queue recently does actually have better answers (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670615/), I just tried the FreeTikZ tool and it seems to work nicely.