# How can I transform a handwritten graph image into a tikzpicture LaTeX code?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have for example a handwritten graph:

[image]

I am looking for a website (or alternative solution) like [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com), which transforms my handwritten graph into a tikzpicture code. So that my output looks like followed:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, auto, scale=0.8, transform shape]
    \node [state] (v0) {$v_0$};
    \node [state, above right=of v0] (v1) {$v_1$};    
    \node [state, below right=of v0] (v2) {$v_2$};    
    \node [state, below=of v0] (v3) {$v_3$};
    \node [state, below=of v3] (v4) {$v_4$};
    \node [state, below right=of v3] (v5) {$v_5$};
    \node [state, below right =of v4] (v6) {$v_6$};
    \path
    (v0) edge[-] node {} (v1);
    \path
    (v0) edge[-] node {} (v2);
    \path
    (v0) edge[-] node {} (v5);
    \path
    (v3) edge[-] node {} (v6);
    \path
    (v4) edge[-] node {} (v2);
    \path
    (v4) edge[-] node {} (v6);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: **(i)** please extend your code fragment to complete small document, **(ii)** how your diagram should like? As is shown on image? If not, please provide the sketch of desired result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sketching free-hand, importing into TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435746/sketching-free-hand-importing-into-tikz)

Comment: Related: [Is There an Online Diagram Graphical Editor that Produces the Corresponding LaTeX Code? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84890/is-there-an-online-diagram-graphical-editor-that-produces-the-corresponding-late)

Comment: 7 points, 6 lines, dots? Tikz it in minutes ... manually.

Comment: This one seems to have better answers than the duplicate, maybe reverse the closure (i.e., close the other question as a duplicate of this one).

Comment: @Marijn What a mess. (but there are some possibly useful answers in the other one too, and that one has more votes overall so... maybe a reasonable option is just to repost useful answers on the other question as community wiki)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [website](https://www.mathcha.io/editor) which can help you draw almost anything.

**It does not automatically transform your hand drawn image**, it only reduces the effort you need to achieve the desired result.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

yEd is a general-purpose graph editor that can import a variety of file formats, including images of hand-drawn graphs. It has a feature to export the graph as TikZ code, which you can then include in your LaTeX document. While it is not able to perfectly recreate the hand-drawn graph, it can save you a significant amount of time and effort compared to manually recreating the graph in TikZ.

[FreeTikz](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/cheunen/freetikz) is a web-based tool to convert hand-drawn diagrams into tikz code. [Click here to run](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/cheunen/freetikz/freetikz.html).

Comment: +1: Is `\usepackage{freetikz}` part of CTAN? I seem not to be able to find it.

Comment: If you click on the link you can download the freetikz.sty from the webpage

Comment: Ah, I should have been investigating more thoroughly

Comment: @JohnSmith I don't see where. But ```tikz``` seems to compile correctly. And the only thing that seems to be done is transform handwritten into tikz picture.