# Difficult TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I need to draw an integration path on top of a circle (with TikZ because I assume it's the best tool for the job), but I don't have any experience with it, and I literally don't know how to start, so what could a skeleton be?

Here it is

[image]

Comment: ctan.org, tikz. Start with the minimal introduction. It shows you concepts quickly, so you can use the big manual for directed search. // Try drawing simple parts first. Refine step by step. Add your attempts as code to your question, so we can have a look.

Comment: Try using [FreeTikz](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/cheunen/freetikz/freetikz.html)

Comment: Look at this helpful answer:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669907/how-can-i-transform-a-handwritten-graph-image-into-a-tikzpicture-latex-code/670615#670615

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Just  a funny remark: in the TiKZ manual one of the fictional people to which the tutorials at the beginning are aimed is just named Karl and titled ***A Picture for Karl’s Students*** :-)

Comment: Would you have an alternate name for _i_? I cannot help read a sad three letter word with that letter. But maybe it is _i_ in the complex plane, in which case I don't see what you can do about that.

Comment: Unfortunately it is the square root of $-1$, yes. @ClaudeChaunier

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can let Ti*k*Z do the calculations:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, decorations.markings}

\newlength{\cx}
\newlength{\cy}
\NewDocumentCommand{\extractangle}{ m O{0pt} O{0pt} m }{
    \pgfextractx{\cx}{\pgfpointanchor{#4}{center}}
    \pgfextracty{\cy}{\pgfpointanchor{#4}{center}}
    \pgfmathparse{atan2(\cy-(#3),\cx-(#2))}
    \let#1=\pgfmathresult
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        font=\scriptsize,
        dot/.style={
            node contents={},
            inner sep=0.5pt,
            circle,
            fill,
        },
        three arrow heads/.style={
            postaction={
                decorate, 
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark={
                        at position -3.885cm
                        with { \arrow{>}}
                    },
                    mark={
                        at position -2.25cm
                        with { \arrow{>}}
                    },
                    mark={
                        at position -0.635cm
                        with { \arrow{>}}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]

% base line
\draw (0:3) -- (180:3);

% coordinates and calculations
\coordinate (A) at (120:2);
\coordinate (B) at (90:2);
\coordinate (C) at (60:2);

\path[name path=CircleA] (A) circle[radius=0.25];
\path[name path=CircleB] (B) circle[radius=0.25];
\path[name path=CircleC] (C) circle[radius=0.25];
\path[name path=Arc] (0:2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=180, radius=2];

\path[name intersections={of=CircleA and Arc, name=i}];
\path[name intersections={of=CircleB and Arc, name=j}];
\path[name intersections={of=CircleC and Arc, name=k}];

\extractangle{\angleA}[cos(120)*2cm][sin(120)*2cm]{i-1}
\extractangle{\angleB}{i-1}
\extractangle{\angleC}{j-1}
\extractangle{\angleD}[0pt][2cm]{j-1}
\extractangle{\angleE}[0pt][2cm]{j-2}
\extractangle{\angleF}{j-2}
\extractangle{\angleG}{k-1}
\extractangle{\angleH}[cos(60)*2cm][sin(60)*2cm]{k-1}

% squarish shape
\draw[three arrow heads]
    ([yshift=0.25cm]120:2) coordinate[label={left:{$B$}}]
    arc[start angle=90, end angle={\angleA}, radius=0.25]
        coordinate[label={below:{$C$}}]
    arc[start angle=\angleB, end angle=\angleC, radius=2]
        coordinate[label={below:{$D$}}]
    arc[start angle={360+\angleD}, end angle=\angleE, radius=0.25]
        coordinate[label={below:{$E$}}]
    arc[start angle=\angleF, end angle=\angleG, radius=2]
        coordinate[label={below:{$F$}}] 
    arc[start angle=\angleH, end angle=90, radius=0.25]
        coordinate[label={right:{$G$}}] 
    -- ++(0,1.25) coordinate[label={above right:{$H$}}] 
    -| coordinate[label={above left:{$A$}}] cycle;

% big arc
\draw 
    (0:2) 
        arc[start angle=0, end angle=60, radius=2] 
        node[dot, label={below:{$-\bar{e}$}}]
    (B) node[dot, label={below:{$i$}}]
    (A) node[dot, label={below:{$e$}}]
        arc[start angle=120, end angle=180, radius=2];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some explanations to help you understand the code:

- I mostly used polar coordinates. These are very helpful when drawing things that are based on circles or arcs. The syntax is `(A:B)` where `A` is the angle (0 degrees is to the east) and B is the distance from the origin.
- I used the `intersections` library to find intersections of different paths, mainly of circles and arcs. Below I added the drawing with some of the helper paths colored to make it more clear where I used intersections. See the [PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) for an in-depth explanation of how this library works.
- I used a macro (`\extractangle`) for which I found inspiration [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/162746/47927) to help me calculate the angle of a given cartesian coordinate using the `atan2()` function provided by PGF. I added two optional arguments to shift the origin, which was needed to calculate all the needed angles.
- Knowing all the coordinates and angles, I was finally able to draw the shapes, and to add the labels and decorations.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, understand it much better now.

Comment: @Karl I added some explanations to my answer. Both, the `\extractangle` macro which essentially uses the `atan2()` function to calculate the angle from a given cartesian coordinate as well as the `intersections` library are necessary for doing the calculations.

Answer (score 11):

A solution via math.

Values that are used more than once are stored in value-keys in the `/tikz` namespace which is why I'm using a short command name for `\tvo`.

The radius of the small arcs as well as their angles will be calculated and stored in `small radius` and `small angle`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newcommand*\tvo[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/#1}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  pics/arrow/.style={/tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code=\pgfarrowdraw{#1}}, pics/arrow/.default=>}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  > = {Straight Barb[angle=60:3pt 1.5]},
  declare function={chord(\a,\r)=2*\r*sin(\a/2);},
  missing angle/.initial=5,
  big radius/.initial=4,
  big angle/.initial=60,
  small radius/.initial/.evaluated={chord(\tvo{missing angle},\tvo{big radius})},
  small angle/.initial/.evaluated={\tvo{big angle}+\tvo{missing angle}/2},
  r-/.style={radius=\tvo{small radius}}, r+/.style={radius=\tvo{big radius}},
  top/.initial=6,
  node font=\scriptsize]
\draw (left:5) -- (right:5);
\draw[r+] (left:\tvo{big radius})
  arc[start angle=180, delta angle=-\tvo{big angle}] coordinate (e)
         (right:\tvo{big radius})
  arc[start angle=0,   delta angle= \tvo{big angle}] coordinate (e');
\coordinate (A) at (e|-0,\tvo{top})
 coordinate (B) at ([shift=(up:\tvo{small radius})] e)
 coordinate (G) at ([shift=(up:\tvo{small radius})] e')
 coordinate (H) at (e'|-0,\tvo{top})
 coordinate (i) at (up:\tvo{big radius});
\draw[r+] (A) -- pic{arrow} (B)
  arc[start angle=90, delta angle=-\tvo{small angle}, r-] coordinate (C)
  arc[start angle=180-\tvo{big angle}-\tvo{missing angle},
        end angle=90+\tvo{missing angle}]                 coordinate (D)
  arc[start angle=180+\tvo{missing angle},
        end angle=-\tvo{missing angle}, r-]               coordinate (E)
  arc[start angle=90-\tvo{missing angle},
        end angle=\tvo{big angle}+\tvo{missing angle}]    coordinate (F)
  arc[end angle=90, delta angle=-\tvo{small angle}, r-] % -- (G) % maybe
  -- pic{arrow} (H) -- pic{arrow} cycle;

\foreach \lab/\pos in {A/above left, B/left, C/below, D/below,
                       E/below, F/below, G/right, H/above right}
  \node[\pos] at (\lab) {$\lab$};
\foreach \pos/\lab in {e, i, e'/-\bar e}
  \fill (\pos) circle[radius=.7pt] node[below=3pt]{$\lab$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Hm, you are right: intersections are not really needed, now that I see this solution =D

Comment: @JasperHabicht Eh, the intersections library is a valid approach. May be best combined with the spath3 library to just remove the various parts of the circles that shouldn't be drawn and just coming those that should. Would mean even less calculations.

Answer (score 7):

Purely for comparison, here is a version in an alternative Latex-friendly language, called [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).

[image]

This is wrapped up in the `luamplib` package, so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path base, hemi, loop;
    base = (left -- right) scaled 200;
    hemi = halfcircle scaled 300;

    % controlling parameters...
    numeric r, c, h; r = 1.27324; c = 12; h = 100;
    pair A, H;
    A = point 4-r of hemi shifted (0, h);
    H = point r   of hemi shifted (0, h);

    loop = buildcycle(
        A -- point 4-r of hemi, 
        subpath (3, 0)  of halfcircle scaled 2c shifted point 4-r of hemi, 
        subpath (4-r,2) of hemi,
        subpath (5, -1) of fullcircle scaled 2c shifted point 2 of hemi, 
        subpath (2, r)  of hemi, 
        subpath (4, 1)  of halfcircle scaled 2c shifted point r of hemi,
        point r of hemi -- H -- A
    );

    % draw loop withcolor red;  % to see the points round the loop...
    % for i=1 upto length loop: dotlabel.top(decimal i, point i of loop); endfor

    interim ahangle := 30;
    drawarrow subpath (-1.5, 0.5) of loop;
    drawarrow subpath (0.5, 19.5) of loop;
    drawarrow subpath (19.5, 20.5) of loop;

    draw base;
    draw subpath (0, r) of hemi;
    draw subpath (4-r, 4) of hemi;

    begingroup; interim labeloffset := 8; dotlabeldiam := 2;
        dotlabel.bot("$-\bar e$", point r of hemi);
        dotlabel.bot("$i$", point 2 of hemi);
        dotlabel.bot("$e$", point 4-r of hemi);
    endgroup;

    drawoptions(withcolor 2/3 red);
    label.ulft("$\scriptstyle A$", A);
    label.lft ("$\scriptstyle B$", point 1 of loop);
    label.bot ("$\scriptstyle C$", point 4 of loop);
    label.bot ("$\scriptstyle D$", point 6 of loop);
    label.bot ("$\scriptstyle E$", point 14 of loop);
    label.bot ("$\scriptstyle F$", point 16 of loop);
    label.rt  ("$\scriptstyle G$", point 19 of loop);
    label.urt ("$\scriptstyle H$", H);
    drawoptions();

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- The drawing is done with three separate paths: `base` is just a horizontal line through the origin;  `hemi` uses the built-in path `halfcircle` to get a suitably scaled semi-circle, but only parts of it are drawn; and `loop`.
- `loop` is created with the `buildcycle` macro: this macro takes a list of paths and produces a closed path that consists of the overlapping parts of the paths.  It works best if all the paths are running in the same direction.
- A complicated path built by `buildcycle` may end up with more control points than it needs; the extra points don't affect the shape but they do make it harder to use `point x of y` and `subpath (a, b) of y`, so the commented out code contains a loop that I used to work out the correct subpaths for the arrows and the lettered labels.
- The "controlling parameters" are: `r` that controls the position of the points "e" and "-e".  r=0 would be on the base, r=2 would make "e" coincide with "i";  `c` is the radius of the circles at the three points; `h` is the height of "A" above "e".

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even know Metapost existed